# Java Program error says cannot find symbol

Tags: java

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

public class Test17
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)    
    {    
        try    
        {       
             StudentInfo si = new StudentInfo("Mac",104,"9823222");
             FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:/student.ser");
             ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
             oos.WriteObject(si);   
             oos.close();
             fos.close();
        }  
        catch(Exception ex)
        {  
             ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `StudentInfo`? Post trace please.

Comment: I dont know. I have typed the prog as it is, as was given. It is giving me error on the StudentInfo line though.

Answer (score 2):

Every time the compiler can not find a part of your code he throws the error "cannot find symbol" when compiling. This problem may occur, e.g. when (1) a class is accessed that is not imported, (2) a variable is used , which was previously not declared or (3) a method is called which does not exist.

In your case, I guess you have to import the StudentInfo class.

Comment: Please can u do the edit of the prog and send me here plz im not getting it :(

Comment: Where do you have this example from? There has to be a StudentInfo class as well.

Comment: i tried to correct the prog but still error iam getting. so can u please correct it for me and send the final prog on here.